# Почему fetch response.text() возвращает Promise

Tags: javascript

Прочитал [в руководстве MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text) о том, как получить из ответа сервера текст, но не очень понял, почему это объект Promise, ведь ответ уже получен, почему нельзя сразу прочитать его?

Например, почему вместо

```
response.text().then(function(text) {
    // ...
});
```

нельзя было бы сделать:

```
var text = response.text();
```

Comment: Я немного изменил ваш вопрос в попытке сделать его чуть более развернутым и детализированным. Если вы не согласны с правкой, можете откатить её =)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev отличная правка!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Не знаю, как у них внутри это работает, могу предположить 2 варианта:

1. Это сделано для унификации интерфейсов, чтоб везде были промисы.
2. Возможно при вызове `fetch` только хедеры читаются, а не сам `body`, только потом при вызове `text()` начинается чтение самого тела запроса. Плюс в момент вызова `text()`, вероятно, только начинается чтение.  То есть, если бы это было синхронно, как вы предлагаете `response.text()`, то это заблочило бы основной поток, а так `response.text().then(...)` сработает только когда файл будет прочитан целиком.

Поправьте, если не прав.

Comment: В принципе в спецификации так и написано: [_The text() method, when invoked, must return the **result of running** consume body with text._](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-body-text)